# How to get a flat view of a TFS item tree?

Tags: tfs

So the tree view in TFS shows items all over the place, clicking one by one is plain stupid monkey work, There must be a way to view all the items in a tree in one flat view, this is what the most of simple web forums have at least, surely there must be something in TFS to enable one to view all the items of a tree in a flat manner, by that I mean if we have this in a tree

```
A Release
 B Feature
  F Task
 C Feature
  D Task
  E Task
```

instead of clicking on each item and going forwards and backwards to read the whole thing we should get a single view as such :

```
A Release
B Feature
F Task
C Feature
D Task
E Task
```

I don't know what the search term is for this (if any) under TFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any way to do this in "Backlogs", you can submit a feature request on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).

However, as an alternative way, you can do this from "Queries". Refer to following steps for details:

1. Create a query to get all the work items you want and save the query. (You can select the flat list or tree list view if you want).
   [image]
2. Open the context menu of the new created query and select "Run Query". Then you will get a UI like following:
   [image]

The upper part of the UI shows all the work items with the view mode you set and the left area show the detailed information about the work item you select. When you click the work items, the detailed information will display.

Comment: Is there an API or Url that I can call to get structure of things from an Item onwards? e.g. getting list of Features/Releases as a josn/xml ? then given a item id I get the tree below that as a json/xml ? I guess that is what the page is already doing, just want to know before reverse engineer it if it is supported.

Comment: @Arjang Check the Rest API for Work Item Tracking: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items