# Tree Explorer View for TFS

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to see the current item being viewed in TFS to be shown in a tree explorer on the side like windows explorer?

Yes, I know there is one view that shows everything in a tree view, but most of the time we are looking at a specific item and have to reconstruct it's relationship to other items from the links list by going forwards, backwards etc.
 Or just clicking a link that opens a new window that displays the current item in a tree view like windows explorer does when we are within a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to change the Parent/Child relationship between Feature, User Story, Task and Bug, you can drag and drop the work item to its parent work item directly. Refer to this link for details: [Map items to group them under a feature or epic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/backlogs/organize-backlog#Mapitemstogroupthemunderafeatureorepic) and [Re-parent and reorder items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/work/backlogs/organize-backlog#Re_parentandreorderitems).

If this does not meet your requirement, refer to my answer in your another question for details: [How to get a flat view of a TFS item tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37127322/how-to-get-a-flat-view-of-a-tfs-item-tree)